# Android Studio logcat does not work on Connected Device but it works perfectly fine on Emulated Device

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, logcat

I can't get my logcat messages for my app when I run it through the real device, but it shows up perfectly fine on emulated devices.

I know my ADB is working because the activity process shows up under Logcat, and I made sure to select the "real device" in logcat so that the correct logcat window is shown. The device also shows up as connected device in Android Studio (and run prompt) and in ADB in the command prompt.

Here are all of the things I have tried:

- Restarted the phone
- Restarted Android Studio
- Restarted Logcat
- Trying different logcat options: verbose, debug, information
- Set filters to "no filter" and emptied my search field
- Tried specific custom filters to see if I can detect specific logcat messages
- Changed USB connection between MTP and PTP
- Changed the target API in the Android manifest to match the API of the connected device
- Invalidated my caches in Android Studio
- Cleaned and rebuilt the project
- Switch from Emulated Device to Connected Device under Logcat
- Turned on USB debugging in device's developer options
- I pretty much made sure to check if I made any amateur mistakes (examples above)
- adb kill-server
- adb start-server
- Changed to higher quality USB cable BRAND NEW
- Changed USB ports just in case one of the USB port is defective
- Installed the manufacturer's device drivers
- In the SDK manager, installed the Google USB drivers

Basically all the millions of things I can see in the emulator's logcat is non-existent on the actual device's logcat.

**Update**: I took @zqcolor's advice to see if my other Android devices is able to report the Logcat logs. Yes it can! However, my app is designed specifically for the ZTE Axon 7 and so I need logcat to work on this device. What to do???

I am stuck and feel hopeless. About to give up!

Comment: I'm wonder maybe I need to install device drivers for my ZTE Axon 7 (the connected device). I can't seem to find it though.

Comment: Try different phones and different computers, with Android Studio 3.0+, this happens from time to time in our dev environment

Comment: Oh wow, it does work on my other Android device. But my app is designed with the ZTE Axon 7 in mind. What should I do? Reinstall Android Studio?

Comment: Then the problem maybe related to ZTE Axon 7's android version, may need upgrade or downgrade, better ask question or support in zte usa website.https://community.zteusa.com/categories/axon

Comment: So I just installed Android Studio on my other PC and ZTE Axon 7 is still not reporting to Logcat. I think this problem is exactly as you said, it has something to do with the Axon 7 itself.

Comment: My guess is zte's firmware's problem, may need upgrade or downgrade the android version on the device

Comment: Found a similar question, not sure it this is the reason "

The Problem is with your custom ROM. It has an incompatible "liblog.so" included. I guess it is not a official build from CyanogenMod.

I would recommend updating to Android 5.0. I found a ROM here: http://androidforums.com/threads/rom-v5-0-lolipop-nightly-for-lg-motion-ms770.882980/
"

Comment: Nope. Stock ROM. But I think your point stands. It's a Chinese company and I don't trust their software quality control.

Comment: But I did manage to fix major bugs on the app without having access to debug tools and Logcat.

Comment: i have the same problem on nougat(7), i might try downgrading the firmware to see if the same issue exists on marshmallow(6)